# Override <input type="file"> value property

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, file-io

It's possible to override value property in  tag? My code in JavaScript

```
var element = document.createElement('input');
element.type = 'FILE';
element.__defineGetter__('value',function(){ return 'ololo'; });
alert(element.value);
```

It show empty string. Also I try override 'value' with prototype

```
function BPFILEINPUT(value)
{
    this.value = value;
}
BPFILEINPUT.prototype = element;
var myFileInput = new BPFILEINPUT('ololo');
alert(myFileInput.value);
```

It work, but crash on

```
form.appendChild(myFileInput);
```

I try pass test for upload form on 4shared.com

```
var uplElems = aUploadForm.elements;


   for (var i = 0; i < uplElems.length; i++) {
       var currentUploadElement = uplElems[i]
       if (currentUploadElement.type == 'file') {
           if (currentUploadElement.value == '') {
               // skip
           } else {
               if (!checkFileLength(currentUploadElement)) {
                  return false;
               }
               filesToUpload += getNumberOfSelectedFiles(currentUploadElement);
           }
       }
   }
   if (filesToUpload < 1) {
       alert('You didn\'t select any file to upload yet.');
       return false;
 }
```

**UPDATE**

I use UIWebView.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you can't set the value of `<input type="file">` programmatically because of *security* reasons. A user has to explicitly click on it to set its value.

Comment: I know about it. For this reason, I tried to override. Maybe there is a way to enable <input type="file"> button in UIWebView through WebKit?

Comment: @user1424203: Search on google "HTML5 File API" that might help but I am not sure.