# Building an input form type file in VueJS Application

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to build a component in VueJS with input field for file type. Here is my component code:

```
<template>
    <div class="flex-col justify-start w-full">
        <div class="mt-2 block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2">{{ label }}</div>
        <input
            class="block appearance-none w-full bg-gray-200 border border-gray-200 text-gray-700 py-3 px-4 pr-8 rounded leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
            :class="errorDisplay ? 'border-red-500 focus:bg-white focus:border-red-500': ''"
            type="file"
            :value="value" @input="emitEvent($event)"
            ref="input_file"
        >
        <span v-if="hint" class="text-xs text-gray-400 font-medium">{{ hint }}</span>
        <span v-if="errorDisplay" class="text-xs text-pink-600 font-medium">{{ errorDisplay }}</span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "InputFile",
        props: {
            label: String,
            hint: {
                type: String,
                default: () => ''
            },
            error: {
                type: Array,
                default: () => []
            },
            placeholder: String,
            value: Object,
        },
        methods: {
            emitEvent(event) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
                reader.onload = () => {
                    const docs = {
                        name: event.target.files[0].name,
                        size: event.target.files[0].size,
                        lastModifiedDate: event.target.files[0].lastModifiedDate,
                        base64: reader.result
                    };
                    console.log(docs);
                    this.$emit('input', docs)
                };
            }
        },
        computed: {
            errorDisplay() {
                if(this.error.length)
                    return this.error.join(', ');
                else
                    return '';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And I'm calling my component as below:

```
<template>
    <div class="flex items-center justify-start">
        <div class="w-1/2 m-2 rounded-lg shadow-lg border b-gray-400 rounded flex flex-col justify-start items-start p-6 bg-white">
            <div class="border-b -m-2 mb-3 px-6 py-2 flex-none w-full justify-start text-gray-700 font-semibold"> Base Controls </div>
            <input-file
                    label="Upload file"
                    v-model="upload_file"
                    :error="errors['upload_file']"
            >
            </input-file>
            <div class="mt-4 text-center">
                <button @click="submit()" class="inline-block px-4 py-2 rounded-lg shadow-md bg-teal-500 hover:bg-teal-400 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline text-white text-sm tracking-wider font-semibold">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import InputFile from "../Elements/Forms/Inputs/File";
    export default {
        name: "Forms",
        components: {
            InputFile,
        },
        data() {
            return {
                upload_file: '',
                errors: {},
            }
        },
        methods: {
            submit() {
                //Submit code...
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

But I'm always getting an error:

> Error in nextTick: "InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string."

I can see my event is getting emitted and `upload_file` has desired value set. To overcome this I made `upload_file` to object but this results in error and the component is also not shown. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue comes from trying to assign to the  element's 'value' property (by binding it to prop.value)

When you're dealing with file-type  elements, you [can't write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803423/override-input-type-file-value-property) to the value property like you can with other  types.

In your custom component's template, delete the binding, `:value="value"`
and in its script either:

- delete the prop `value: Object` or,
- if you need to assign the value prop for v-model compatibility, assign it to File. eg: `value: File`

*note:* This will work, but you'll get a Vue warning: 'type check failed' for an invalid prop when the component is called without a supplied file.

ie...

```
<template>
    <div class="flex-col justify-start w-full">
        <div class="mt-2 block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2">{{ label }}</div>
        <input
            class="block appearance-none w-full bg-gray-200 border border-gray-200 text-gray-700 py-3 px-4 pr-8 rounded leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
            :class="errorDisplay ? 'border-red-500 focus:bg-white focus:border-red-500': ''"
            type="file"
            @input="emitEvent($event)"
            ref="input_file"
        >
        <span v-if="hint" class="text-xs text-gray-400 font-medium">{{ hint }}</span>
        <span v-if="errorDisplay" class="text-xs text-pink-600 font-medium">{{ errorDisplay }}</span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "InputFile",
        props: {
            label: String,
            hint: {
                type: String,
                default: () => ''
            },
            error: {
                type: Array,
                default: () => []
            },
            placeholder: String,
            value: File,
        },
        methods: {
            emitEvent(event) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
                reader.onload = () => {
                    const docs = {
                        name: event.target.files[0].name,
                        size: event.target.files[0].size,
                        lastModifiedDate: event.target.files[0].lastModifiedDate,
                        base64: reader.result
                    };
                    console.log(docs);
                    this.$emit('input', docs)
                };
            }
        },
        computed: {
            errorDisplay() {
                if(this.error.length)
                    return this.error.join(', ');
                else
                    return '';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

should be ok.